# How to check if (https://) is a image or web link

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to check if a hyperlink is a image link or web link.

```
image_list = []
url = 'http://www.image.jpg/'
if any(x in '.jpg .gif .png .jpeg' for x in url):
    image_list.append(url)
else:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup =  BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")

    for link in soup.find_all('img'):
        src = link.get('src')
        if src.startswith("https"):
            image_list.append(src)
```

The code above works in finding out the hyperlink contains image formats, however whenever i use a link that does not contain ".jpg ect..." it still appends the link to the image_list and skips the else statement.

Comment: Is there possibly a way you can figure out if `any(x in '...' for x in url)` is doing what you expect? That might help you narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at this code:

```
any(x in '.jpg .gif .png .jpeg' for x in url):
```

This checks if any *letter* in the URL is in the string.  The `'p'` from `http` is in the string, so you will always get a true result.

Here's how you could check the extension of a URL:

```
import posixpath
import urllib.parse

IMAGE_EXTS = { '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif' }

url = 'http://example.com/'
if posixpath.splitext(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path)[1] in IMAGE_EXTS:
    # Has image extension...
```

But that's a moot point, because the extension of a URL doesn't tell you whether it's an image.  Unlike regular files, for URLs, the extension is completely irrelevant! You can have an `.html` URL which gives you a PNG image, or a `.gif` URL which is really an HTML web page. You need to check the Content-Type of the HTTP reply.